# How to find plugin vimscript function definition?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, ide

Assume I am using some plugin function
e.g. For vim-plug, I put this code in my .vimrc at the end

```
call plug#end()
```

How to find out where is this function `plug#end()` is located? from vimrc directly itself

Currently I do following

```
$ cd ~/.vim/plugged
$ grep -nrs 'somefunction' .
```

Doing this every time is cumbersome. Is there any clean way to know that function location?

Answer (score 8):

There are several approaches:

#### Open the file

As others have explained, unless the author doesn't follow conventions, the function `scope1#scope2#...#scopen#funcname()` is supposed to be defined in `{rtp}/autoload/scope1/scope2/.../scopen.vim` file.

Where `{rtp}` designates any directory in [`'runtimepath'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27rtp%27) list option. This option is usually automatically handled by plugin managers.

I've been using a very old [plugin](https://github.com/LucHermitte/SearchInRuntime) of mine to open any file anywhere in `{rtp}`

```
:SearchInRuntime sp autoload/plug.vim
```

would [split open (`:sp`)](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3Asp) the first file named `autoload/plug.vim` in the runtime path. Command-line completion is supported.

This approach only work with autoloaded function.

#### Jump to the function (tags)

This previous approach permits to open the file, but we still have to jump to the function definition. In my workflow, I automatically generate [tags](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/tagsrch.txt.html#tags) for everything under `~/.vim`.

Vim offers several commands to navigate around, but tags generation is still up to us. There exist many approaches and plugins. I'm using here another [plugin](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-tags) of mine for tag generation, and tag navigation.

What is interesting in lh-tags, given the need to jump to a function, is `:LHTags` command. As `:tag` it can take the symbol searched as parameter, but it also supports a kind of fuzzy matching search while `:tag` needs us to be explicit

```
:tag plug#end  " explicit
:LHTags pl en  " "fuzzy"
```

This approach will be tricky with script local functions that exists in several files. `:LHTags` will display all overloads.

Anonymous functions can't be found this way.

#### Ask vim what it knows about the function

```
:verbose function funcname
```

will return were a function is defined, and its definition.

This will work with every kind of functions:

- for script local function, the ScriptNumbeR is required
- even anonymous functions are supported, as long as their object hasn't been garbage-collected.

#### Jump to an error

Sometimes we want to jump to a function that appears in an error message. In my root [library-plugin](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib), I provide a function that decodes the last error message(s) and fills the [quickfix-window](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#quickfix-window) with the backtrace of the error. The [function](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/doc/Callstack.md#lhexceptionsay_what) is not packaged into a command in my plugin, but it's quite simple to do:

```
" .vimrc
" Parameter: number of errors to decode, default: "1"
command! -nargs=? WTF call lh#exception#say_what(<q-args>)
```

This will work with every kind of function, even anonymous functions that haven't been GC'ed with their owner object.

Comment: When using `verbose function` you'll want to be using it thusly: `:verbose function /FunctionName` .. the key being the `/` which will search for functions matching the regex pattern. Otherwise you will often get no results.

Comment: @Orwellophile. Thanks, I missed this usage of `:verbose function`. Also, I was answering with the expectation we know the exact function name, either because we see it written before our eyes, or from an error message. In error message cases, I must confess I do not hesitate a single moment to click-select with the mouse and paste a function name in the command line with a middle-click. Hence I've never have a need for the extra `/`.

Answer (score 4):

With tpope’s [scriptease](https://github.com/tpope/vim-scriptease), you can do `:Vedit autoload/plug.vim` (with completion) to get to the file, but you still have to know that `plug#` signifies a function in the `plug` « namespace » of the autoload system.

(Note: not all plugin authors respect this. Some create functions `foo#bar` in `plugin/foo.vim`, which is seriously misleading! The function is neither autoloaded nor located in the autoload directory, but rather *masquerades as something that it’s not.* If you’re reading this, please only put `#` in autoload! `/endrant`)

Answer (score 3):

This is a `:h autoload` function, it's name is a hint on where it's defined.

`plug` is the name of this script (without `.vim`), it's parent directory is `some_runtimepath/autoload` . You already know it's `vim-plug`, so goto `~/.vim/plugged/autoload`, you should see `plug.vim` there.

You can also use directory with `autoload`, for example : `a#b#c#d#foo#bar` is a function defined at `some_runtimepath/autoload/a/b/c/d/foo.vim`.

If you have trouble find out where the `some_runtimepath` is, use this command:

```
:verbose function plug#end
--------
   function plug#end()
        Last set from /usr/local/source/.vim/autoload/plug.vim line 247
     ...
```

If you have create tags for your `.vim`, you can place cursor at `plug#end` and use `c-]` to jump to it's definition directly.